# Azure search API - search filter syntax

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using the azure search api trying to filter by a certain field value:  businesstype = store.   It always returns 3 stores, even though I should have thousands.  I can't tell for sure what's inside the index. In the Azure search web portal I type businessType eq 'store' and it gives me two stores, then starts returning businesstype = restaurant.  Not sure what is going on.  We have other implementations in other projects where filters are working.    Here's code that I'm executing as it is invoked by using ASP.NET Web API

```
  var indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(GlobalSettings.SearchServiceName, $"businesses{GlobalSettings.Environment}", new SearchCredentials(GlobalSettings.SearchServiceAdminApiKey));

        if (latitude == null && longitude == null)
        {
            //chicago
            latitude = 41.8333925;
            longitude = -88.0121478;
        }

        // get all attributes and camel case them
        var attributes = typeof(BusinessSearchItem).GetProperties().Select(x => char.ToLowerInvariant(x.Name[0]) + x.Name.Substring(1)).ToList();
        var parameters = new SearchParameters
        {
            Select = attributes,
            QueryType = QueryType.Full,
            Top = take,
            Skip = skip,
            IncludeTotalResultCount = true,
            OrderBy = new List<string>() { $"geo.distance(location, geography'POINT({longitude} {latitude})')" }
        };

        // filters
        string filter = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(businessType))
        {
            switch (businessType.ToLower())
            {
                case "restaurant":
                    filter += "businessType eq 'Restaurant'";
                    break;

                case "store":
                    filter += "businessType eq 'Store'";
                    break;
            }// end switch on business type
        }

        parameters.Filter = filter;

        try
        {
            // run the search
            var results = indexClient.Documents.Search<BusinessSearchItem>(q, parameters);
            Logger.Log.Info($"Search conducted. Query: {q} Business Type: {businessType} Lat: {latitude} Long: {longitude} User: {username}");
            var businessDTOs = results.Results.Select(x => new BusinessDTO
            {
             .........
            ).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

the model BusinessSearchItem has a field BusinessType of string that has the attribute searchable. The skip is 0 and take 40.

Comment: You mention that BusinessType is marked as searchable. Is it also marked as filterable? If not, I’d expect Search to throw CloudException.

Comment: Also, the casing of Store and Restaurant is inconsistent throughout your question. Filtering is case-sensitive, so it matters how you capitalize the literals. Can you confirm whether the casing of these values is consistent in the index? One way to check would be to facet on businessType without a filter, assuming it’s facetable. As for the Portal, it would help if you share the query string that you used.

Comment: Bruce, thanks for responding.  BusinessType is also marked as IsFilterable.  When I populate the index, I'm calling ToString on a BusinessType enum so I'm sure they've all got 'Store' with a capital S.  In the portal, the query is like so:  https://.....search.windows.net/indexes/businessesstaging/docs?api-version=2019-05-06&search=businessType%20eq%20'Store'

Comment: It occurred to me I don't know whether you're talking about the property NAME or VALUE when referring to the casing.  The serach model has a public string BusinessType with filterable and serachable attributes.  I see the code is calling businesstype = 'Store' with a small b, is that what you mean?

Comment: I dropped and recreated the whole index, but strangely in the portal, it shows the property of businessType with a small b.  I don't know why

Comment: Ok I think I found out why.  My code to repopulate the index above seems to stop around 550,000 for no apparent reason.  Thereforre, there are actually only 3 stores in the index.  The rest are after row 600,000 in the db. This means the query syntax is right, and the portal just returns more non results with lower search score.  I have to figure out how to populate the index with over a million items

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Note that your query in the portal wasn’t working as expected because you’re using the “search” parameter instead of the $filter parameter.

Comment: Also, field names and values are both case-sensitive in filters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197892/discussion-between-patrick-goode-and-bruce-johnston).

Comment: @PatrickGoode If your issue has been resolved, please add the answer to the answer part. Then this issue can be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the search at all, it was that the data was not in the index